# No mapping exists from DB type AnsiString to known sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I built a query from a joint table, when I test it in the query builder it works fine but before I finish the wizard I get this message *"no mapping exists from DB type AnsiString to known sql server"*.

I ignored the message then I tested the query function inside the windows form using C# language, when I run the program I got an exception with the similar message:*No mapping exists from DbType AnsiString to a known SqlDbType.*.

here is my code:

```
SELECT SUM(Sales_Details.SalesP) AS Expr1
FROM Sales_Details INNER JOIN
Sales ON Sales_Details.Sl_ID = Sales.Sl_ID
WHERE (@date1 > Sales.Sl_Date) AND (@date2 < Sales.Sl_Date)
```

I tried to troubleshoot the issue, I deleted the last line of the code which is
 `WHERE (@date1 > Sales.Sl_Date) AND (@date2 < Sales.Sl_Date)`
 then the code works fine!!
I changed the data type of the parameters of the query to a `DateTime` but still showing the same exception error.
Here is my C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
        DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);

        int s = (int)queriesTableAdapter1.sellSumByDate(d1, d2);
        MessageBox.Show("The total sells is "+s);

    }
```

AGAIN I am sure that the exception is showing because of this line of code `WHERE (@date1 > Sales.Sl_Date) AND (@date2 < Sales.Sl_Date)`
what is the wrong with my code PLEASE?
or the problem is with my SQL or database version?

Comment: How do you add the parameters in your c# code?

Comment: @Johnbot please check out the last edition. I added more interesting information.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server CE?

Comment: @Dd2 How can I know what version of SQL server I have?
I am using Visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, when you are using `SqlCeCommand` and `ConnectionString`, you have to add parameters

as shown below (You will have the required data in dataset Ds1.):

> string con_str = "..."; // connection string
>
> // initialise datetime variable with a proper datetime value
>
> DateTime date1 = ... ;
>
> DateTime date2 = ... ;
>
> Database1DataSet Ds1 = new Database1DataSet(); // if you are reading from Database1
>
> SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(con_str);
>
> conn.Open();
>
> SqlCeCommand Sqlce = new SqlCeCommand();
>
> Sqlce.Connection = conn;
>
> Sqlce.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Sales_Details.SalesP) AS Expr1 " +
>
> ```
>                    "FROM Sales_Details INNER JOIN " +
>
>                    "Sales ON Sales_Details.Sl_ID = Sales.Sl_ID " +
>
>                    "WHERE (@date1 > Sales.Sl_Date) AND (@date2 < Sales.Sl_Date)";
> ```
>
> // add parameter values
>
> Sqlce.Parameters.AddWithValue(@date1, date1);
>
> Sqlce.Parameters.AddWithValue(@date2, date2);
>
> SqlCeDataReader reader = Sqlce.ExecuteReader(); // this command executes your query
>
> while (reader.Read())
>
> {
>
> ```
> Ds1.YourTable.Rows.Add(reader[0], reader[1], reader[2],..., reader[last column index]);
> ```
>
> }
>
> reader.Close();
>
> conn.Close();